# How to compare time in php to return a different string at different times

Tags: php, function, time

I would like that a distinction is made in the morning, afternoon and evening, to achive that other text will be placed when you look at another time. I tried this but it does not work :(

**THIS IS MY CODE**

```
<?php
function tijd($unixtijd = 0){
    date('H:i:s', $unixtijd);
    if('H'>'18'){
        $good = 'good evening';
    }
    if('H'<'18' || 'H'>'12'){
        $good = 'good afternoon';
    }
    else{
        $good = 'good morning';
    }
    return $good;
}
?>
```

**somewhere else in the code**

```
<?php
echo tijd(time());?>
```

I hope someone can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've to store the variable, correction for your code would be:

```
<?php
function tijd(){
    $hour = date('H');
    if($hour > 18){
        $good = 'good evening';
    }
    if($hour <= 18 && $hour >= 12){
        $good = 'good afternoon';
    }
    else{
        $good = 'good morning';
    }
    return $good;
}

echo tijd();
?>
```

You were literally comparing the character 'H' with the character '18'